# Objective-C JSON types

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, macos, nsjsonserialization

I'm using [`NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) in an iOS 5 project to read a JSON string and convert it to a Foundation object. Is there an easy way to find out if the object or some of its children are arrays, dictionaries, numbers or strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if the returned object is a certain class with the `-isKindOfClass:` method. For example, to check if it's an array:

```
id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:...]
if ([jsonObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] {
    // Do array stuff...
}
```

Similarly for the other foundation types.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful about using `NSJSONSerialization` since it is only supported on iOS 5.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7+.

I think you can also have a try with third-party libraries, such as:

- [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) (faster than `NSJSONSerialization` per its introduction)
- [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Both are easy to use and flexible.

Comment: I've been using the **SBJson Framework** for quite some time, and it's been working great for me... ;-)

Comment: That's nice, but it does not really answer the question... This could be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

All objects can answer their class.  Even more useful, you can ask if something is a member of a class or any of it's subclasses:

```
id jsonParse;

if ([jsonParse isKindOfClass:[NSArray self]]) {
    for (id element in (NSArray *)jsonParse) {

        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: `[NSArray self]` looks weird (although it does work); `[NSArray class]` is much more typical idiomatic Objective-C.

Comment: It's more typical, but just a little bit wronger.  To ask a class for it's class is to ask for it's meta-class (a concept mercifully absent from Objective C).  Asking a class for itself, however, is clear, correct, and dare I say ... classy.